# Service URL for Web Feature Service (WFS) using GML Simple Features profile?

Tags: wfs, gml

Does anyone know of an "almost always available" Service URL for a Web Feature Service (WFS) using GML Simple Features profile?

I'm keen to test WFS client capabilities without having to configure a WFS server.

## UPDATE

The [Answer to this Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/can-use-of-gml-simple-features-profile-by-web-feature-service-wfs-be-spotted) provides advice on how to determine if a given WFS appears to be using SFGML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [USGS National Map Gazetteer](http://services.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/geonames/MapServer) - [GetCapabilities](http://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/geonames/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS)
2. [Geologic Map of Arizona](http://www.azgs.az.gov/services_azgeomap.shtml) - [GetCapabilities](http://services.azgs.az.gov/ArcGIS/services/GeologicMapOfArizona/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS)