# Can use of GML Simple Features profile by Web Feature Service (WFS) be advertised?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, wfs, gml, ogc

The ArcGIS 10.1 documentation on [Working with WFS services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00370000000m000000) says:

> The GML Simple Features profile is recommended for use with ArcGIS and
>   is the basis for WFS support in ArcGIS.

Is there an easy way to determine whether a particular WFS is encoding using that or an alternative profile - perhaps by looking at its [GetCapabilities](http://nsidc.org/cgi-bin/atlas_south?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.0)?

It's interesting to note that not a single service URL was suggested when I asked whether anyone knew of a [public WFS using the Simple Features profile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31208/service-url-for-web-feature-service-wfs-using-gml-simple-features-profile).

I'm also trying to uncover an answer to this via the [ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65349-How-to-determine-whether-WFS-is-using-GML-Simple-Features-profile) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in **GetCapabilities** and **DescribeFeatureType** as stated in the [GML Simple Feature profile documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=11266&ei=UDE2ULqcEoSo8QTfvoCYCQ&usg=AFQjCNH9-rGUh2AYR1zGOk_m3mlfUEGTrw&sig2=hS4RpzWNaUnmESiiJdWsmA):

## GetCapabilities:

> The following XML fragment shows how a WFS may advertise in its
>   capabilities document that it can generate schemas that comply with
>   this profile:

```xml
1. <ows:Operation name="DescribeFeatureType">
2.   <ows:DCP>
3.     <ows:HTTP>
4.       <ows:Post xlink:href="http://www.BlueOx.org/wfs"/>
5.     </ows:HTTP>
6.   </ows:DCP>
7.   <ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
8.     <ows:Value>text/xml; subType=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
9.     <ows:Value>text/xml; subType=gml/3.1.1/sfgml</Value>
10.   </ows:Parameter>
11. </ows:Operation>
```

> **Line 9** indicates that this WFS can generate a GML application schema that conforms to this profile.

## DescribeFeatureType XML-encoded request:

> The following example XML fragment shows a DescribeFeatureType request
>   indicating that the response should conform to this profile:

```xml
<DescribeFeatureType outputFormat="text/xml; subType=gml/3.1.1/sfgml"/>
```

## DescribeFeatureType KVP-encode request:

> The following example URL shows a DescribeFeatureType request
>   indicating that the response should conform to this profile:
>
> `http://www.BlueOx.org/wfs/wfs.cgi?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&outputFormat=text/xml;+subType=gml/3.1.1/sfgml`

Comment: Do you happen to also know of an "almost always available" Service URL for a Web Feature Service (WFS) using GML Simple Features profile?  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31208/service-url-for-web-feature-service-wfs-using-gml-simple-features-profile

Comment: I wasn't able to find any NON-ArcGIS sfgml compliant WFS services. I would have liked to have found some that weren't from arcGIS server, but doesn't mean that they don't exist. Check my answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32150/2022)

Comment: I guess that part of the answer here is that the 'GML simple features profile' document (http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=11266) is not an OGC standard; so whilst that document shows a way that a simple feature WFS may show such support, it isn't the only way to do so.