# Viewing a WFS in ArcMap 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, wfs

I'm trying to view some Environment Agency (EA) WFS data in ArcMap 10.2.2. I've installed the Data Interoperability extension and enabled it. I've added a new connection with the url below. It should contain the EA's main river dataset. When I load the WFS, the layer appears in the table of contents, but contains no features.

EA Main River WFS URL: http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENTWFS--25dde009-ba7d-40de-8380-c5c3bb32ccdc&VERSION=1.0.0

(WFS available from http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/catalogue/#/catalogue)

Comment: I should add, I'm able to view the WFS correctly in QGIS 2.18, but my colleagues require this to be viewable in ArcMap.

Comment: the [GetCapabiliites response](http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENTWFS--25dde009-ba7d-40de-8380-c5c3bb32ccdc&VERSION=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities&) shows a different location for the actual service.  Perhaps ArcMap can't handle the redirect.  What if you use the actual service URL advertised?

Comment: Are you using the GML Simple Features profile?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/can-use-of-gml-simple-features-profile-by-web-feature-service-wfs-be-advertise

Comment: Hi nmtoken and Polygeo. Thanks for the responses - I'm not entirely sure what you both mean. What I do know is I've used this method - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Connecting_to_a_WFS_service/00370000000p000000/ with the URL above. What is the service URL? And I doubt I'm using the GML Simple Features profile.

Comment: if you follow the link I give in my comment (which is your original URL with parameters to do a GetCapabilities request) you can see that the listed GET URL for the service is actually `<Get onlineResource="http://www.geostore.com/OGC/OGCInterface;jsessionid=wZlXLOq+AimpsFhn4WQsUXjV?SESSIONID=1326425477&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENTWFS&"/>`  So what if you use that URL as your service endpoint.

Comment: The geostore service above is provided by `MapServer version 6.4.3` which can only do a simple feature WFS AFAIK, so it should be readable by ArcMap

Comment: I've used your suggested URL, but I'm getting the error: "Failed to retrieve feature types.   <WFS> Unable to fetch the capabilities document: 'http://www.geostore.com:80/OGC/OGCInterface;jse?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&?ssionid=wZlXLOq+Aimp??sFhn4WQsUXjV?SESSION??ID=1326425477&INTERF??ACE=ENVIRONMENTWFS&VERSION=1.0.0'"

Comment: Using your URL works fine in QGIS too.

Comment: I've since received an upgrade to ArcGIS 10.4.1 - still no luck.